# Which is a better way of writing this code?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, styles, frontend, material-ui

Option 1:

```
className={
          data.msg.length > 48
            ? `${classes.message} ${classes.longMessage}`
            : `${classes.message}`
        }
```

Option 2:

```
className={`${classes.message} ${
  data.msg.length > 48 ? classes.longMessage : ""
}`}
```

Is there any performance difference too? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally agree with the readability what `@noob` mentioned in the answer earlier.

From data side let me configure the following below:

```
// I assume you are getting this from an API or somewhere else
const data = {
   msg: 'Testing text for stackoverflow'
};
```

From that perspective my suggestion would be to go with the following option:

```
let messageClassName = `${classes.message}`;

if (data.msg.length > 48) {
   messageClassName = `${classes.message} ${classes.longMessage}`;
}

return (
   <div className={messageClassName}>
      {data.msg}
   </div>
)
```

Most of the time readability helps.

Answer (score 2):

They're pretty much the same, and choosing one over the other will have no *noticeable* effect on the performance of your app. The only thing you will want to consider in this circumstance is the readability - in which case I would argue that the first example would be preferable, but that's entirely subjective.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the top one is faster, here is my reasoning:

Both will have one ternary expression - Where you are using it does not change it's speed, but the commands executed after expression will, and this is what make the first faster, eg:

Case expression TRUE: ( no - difference )

Both will have to concatenate

Case expression FALSE: ( Top one faster )

Top one just evaluate

Botton one concatenate and evaluate

But to do this is too much preciosim.